# Running a shell script through an automated Powershell folder listener

Tags: powershell, curl, sendgrid

Over the last couple of days, I've been putting together a Powershell script to watch of particular folder on my c drive for new files with the help of [mcpcmag's articule](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/05/01/monitor-windows-folder-for-new-files.aspx). The new files will be created when an email is requested by the end user. The new file is a .sh file containing a cURL command which sends a post request to the [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) API.

Here's the powershell script below:

```
# Create a listener for our emailOut directory 
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

# Set the path and turn on the listener 
$watcher.Path = 'C:\emailOut'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action =
{
    # set the shellScript to the full path of the added file
    $shellScript = $event.SourceEventArgs.fullPath
    # get the name of the file
    $name = (Get-Item $shellScript).Name
    # set the path which the file will be moved to on completion
    $oldFolderDir = "C:\emailOut\old\" + $name
    
    # run the script
    & $shellScript

    # set the log file path
    $logFile = "C:\emailOut\emailLog_" + $(get-date -format FileDate) + ".txt"

    # set the log message
    $logInfo = $name + " ---> " + $(get-date)

    # add entry to log file
    $logInfo | Out-File $logFile -Append -encoding utf8


    # Move the script file into the historic folder
    Move-Item -Path $shellScript -Destination $oldFolderDir

}

# Start the watcher
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
```

The comments make the process fairly self explanatory but to briefly describe, here is what happens (or should happen):

1. File goes into folder that is being watched
2. Shell script is run
3. Entry is added to the logFile
4. File is moved to the old folder
5. Done

Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with the way I am running the shell script. When running the process, it is obvious that the script is running as a black box appear for a fraction of a second but no email is sent. I have checked the original script and there are no issues because when I double click on the .sh file the email is sent perfectly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share my final working solution.
I did try `Start-Sleep -seconds 5` prior to running the script but this unfortunately did not have the expected results.

After a bit of trial and error I arrived at a working solution:

```
# Create a listener for our emailOut directory 
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

# Set the path and turn on the listener 
$watcher.Path = 'C:\emailOut'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action =
{
   # set the shellScript to the full path of the added file
   $shellScript = $event.SourceEventArgs.fullPath
   # get the name of the file
   $name = (Get-Item $shellScript).Name
   #set the path which the file will be moved to on completion
   $oldFolderDir = "C:\emailOut\old\" + $name

   #### SOLUTION START ###

   #go to where bash.exe is stored
   cd "C:\Program Files\Git\bin"

   # run the script
   & .\bash.exe $shellScript

   ### SOLUTION END ###

   # set the log file path
   $logFile = "C:\emailOut\emailLog_" + $(get-date -format FileDate) + ".txt"

   # set the log message
   $logInfo = $name + " ---> " + $(get-date)

   # add entry to log file
   $logInfo | Out-File $logFile -Append -encoding utf8


   # Move the script file into the historic folder
   Move-Item -Path $shellScript -Destination $oldFolderDir

  }

  # Start the watcher
  Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
```

Basically, I ran my script by passing my cURL script to git bash.exe.
Any further queries or questions feel free to contact me.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a logical problem here:

> File goes into folder that is being watched 
> [PowerShell]Shell script is run

The problem is after you call `Register-ObjectEvent`, your script ends, powershell process terminates, and this removes FileSystemWatcher implicitly.
You should keep script running all the time you want to 'catch' events.

You can run it through scheduled task, with option `Do not start a new instance` *if there is instance running* and set to repeat every N minutes *(to restore script if something fails or someone kills process, etc.)*. This PowerShell instance must be running to keep getting events.

```
$eventSI = 'CustomSI_FSWCreated'

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = 'S:\SCRIPTS\FileTest'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = { [System.Console]::WriteLine($event.SourceEventArgs.fullPath) }

# Start the watcher
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Created' -Action $action -SourceIdentifier $eventSI | Out-Null
try
{
    $l = 1;
    while($true)    
    {
        # Actually this timeout only sets the frequence of dots on your screen. Set it bigger if you want or remove Write-Host-s
        Wait-Event -Timeout 1 
        Write-Host "." -NoNewline
        $l++;
        if ($l -ge 40) 
        {
            Write-Host ""
            $l = 1;
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    # This executes when you press Ctrl+C
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventSI
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $watcher.Dispose()
    Write-Host "Unregistered FSWE"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @filmonic for your suggestion. You are right in saying that the task needs to be left running so will put your example into practice so I can run it as a scheduled task. However, I don't think this answers the original question though as the part that has the issue is where I run the script. I.e. '& $shellScript'.

Comment: # run the script |    & $shellScript << You mean here? You want to run _file that someone put into folder_, right ? I'd recommend to make a delay before run. File can be created, but not written yet.